# How can you connect Django code with Python?

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django and Python. I'm currently building a crawler that searches for emails and I currently have a crawler build with Python. But I want it to be linked to a search bar in Django that when it is clicked, the code detects the URL and the Python code starts running. I don't know how to proceed doing this.

For now, I've tried to put the code in views.py and connect it to a url.py and connecting that url to a button. But it doesn't work.

Here is the crawler code:

```
import re
import requests
import requests.exceptions
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urljoin
from lxml import html
import sys
import csv


class EmailCrawler:

    processed_urls = set()
    unprocessed_urls = set()
    emails = set()

    def __init__(self, website: str):
        self.website = website
        self.unprocessed_urls.add(website)
        self.headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/78.0.3904.70 Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
        }
        self.base_url = urlsplit(self.website).netloc
        self.outputfile = self.base_url.replace('.','_')+'.csv'
        # we will use this list to skip urls that contain one of these extension. This will save us a lot of bandwidth and speedup the crawling process
        # for example: www.example.com/image.png --> this url is useless for us. we cannot possibly parse email from images and all other types of files.
        self.garbage_extensions = ['.aif','.cda','.mid','.midi','.mp3','.mpa','.ogg','.wav','.wma','.wpl','.7z','.arj','.deb','.pkg','.rar','.rpm','.tar.gz','.z','.zip','.bin','.dmg','.iso','.toast','.vcd','.csv','.dat','.db','.dbf','.log','.mdb','.sav','.sql','.tar','.apk','.bat','.bin','.cgi','.pl','.exe','.gadget','.jar','.py','.wsf','.fnt','.fon','.otf','.ttf','.ai','.bmp','.gif','.ico','.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.ps','.psd','.svg','.tif','.tiff','.asp','.cer','.cfm','.cgi','.pl','.part','.py','.rss','.key','.odp','.pps','.ppt','.pptx','.c','.class','.cpp','.cs','.h','.java','.sh','.swift','.vb','.ods','.xlr','.xls','.xlsx','.bak','.cab','.cfg','.cpl','.cur','.dll','.dmp','.drv','.icns','.ico','.ini','.lnk','.msi','.sys','.tmp','.3g2','.3gp','.avi','.flv','.h264','.m4v','.mkv','.mov','.mp4','.mpg','.mpeg','.rm','.swf','.vob','.wmv','.doc','.docx','.odt','.pdf','.rtf','.tex','.txt','.wks','.wps','.wpd']
        self.email_count = 0

    def crawl(self):
        """
        It will continue crawling until the list unprocessed urls list is empty
        """

        url = self.unprocessed_urls.pop()
        print("CRAWL : {}".format(url))
        self.parse_url(url)


        if len(self.unprocessed_urls)!=0:
            self.crawl()
        else:
            print('End of crawling for {} '.format(self.website))
            print('Total urls visited {}'.format(len(self.processed_urls)))
            print('Total Emails found {}'.format(self.email_count))
            print('Dumping processed urls to {}'.format(self.base_url.replace('.','_')+'.txt'))
            with open(self.base_url.replace('.','_')+'.txt' ,'w') as f:
                f.write('\n'.join(self.processed_urls))

    def parse_url(self, current_url: str):
        """
        It will load and parse a given url. Load it and find all the url in this page.
        It also filters the urls and adds them to unprocessed url list.
        Finally it scrapes the emails if found on the page and the updates the email list

        INPUT:
            current_url: URL to parse
        RETURN:
            None
        """

        #we will retry to visit a url for 5 times in case it fails. after that we will skip it in case if it still fails to load
        response = requests.get(current_url, headers=self.headers)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
        urls = tree.xpath('//a/@href')  # getting all urls in the page


        #Here we will make sure that we convert the sub domain to full urls
        # example --> /about.html--> https://www.website.com/about.html
        urls = [urljoin(self.website,url) for url in urls]
        # now lets make sure that we only include the urls that fall under our domain i.e filtering urls that point outside our main website.
        urls = [url for url in urls if self.base_url == urlsplit(url).netloc]


        #removing duplicates
        urls = list(set(urls))


        #filtering  urls that point to files such as images, videos and other as listed on garbage_extensions
        #Here will loop through all the urls and skip them if they contain one of the extension
        parsed_url = []
        for url in urls:
            skip = False
            for extension in self.garbage_extensions:
                if not url.endswith(extension) and  not url.endswith(extension+'/'):
                    pass
                else:
                    skip = True
                    break
            if not skip:
                parsed_url.append(url)

        # finally filtering urls that are already in queue or already visited
        for url in parsed_url:
            if url not in self.processed_urls and url not in self.unprocessed_urls:
                self.unprocessed_urls.add(url)


        #parsing email
        self.parse_emails(response.text)
        # adding the current url to processed list
        self.processed_urls.add(current_url)



    def parse_emails(self, text: str):
        """
        It scans the given texts to find email address and then writes them to csv
        Input:
            text: text to parse emails from
        Returns:
            bool: True or false (True if email was found on page)
        """
        # parsing emails and then saving to csv
        emails = set(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+', text, re.I))
        #TODO: sometime "gFJS3amhZEg_z39D5EErVg@2x.png" gets accepted as email with the above regex. so for now I will check if email ends with jpeg,png and jpg

        for email in emails:
            skip_email = False
            for checker in ['jpg','jpeg','png']:
                if email.endswith(checker):
                    skip_email = True
                    break

            if not skip_email:
                if email not in self.emails:
                    with open(self.outputfile, 'a', newline='') as csvf:
                        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvf)
                        csv_writer.writerow([email])
                    self.email_count +=1
                    self.emails.add(email)
                    print(' {} Email found {}'.format(self.email_count,email))

        if len(emails)!=0:
            return True
        else:
            return False



print('WELCOME TO EMAIL CRAWLER')
try:
    website = sys.argv[1]
except:
    website = input("Please enter a website to crawl for emails:")
crawl = EmailCrawler(website)
crawl.crawl()
```

Here is the html code:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Email Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <!-- Search form -->
  <div class="container">
      <br/>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                          <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
                              <form class="card card-sm" action="Search/">
                                  <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
                                      <div class="col-auto">
                                          <i class="fas fa-search h4 text-body"></i>
                                      </div>
                                      <!--end of col-->
                                      <div class="col">
                                          <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" type="search" placeholder="Search topics or keywords">
                                      </div>
                                      <!--end of col-->
                                      <div class="col-auto">
                                          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" onclick="">Search</button>
                                      </div>
                                      <!--end of col-->
                                  </div>
                              </form>
                          </div>
                          <!--end of col-->
                      </div>


  </div>
</html>
```

Any help would really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you post your view and urls.py also please?

Comment: `from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import generics, status

def index(request):
 return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/main.html')`

Above is the views

`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

]`

Here is the urls

Answer (score 0):

Your html code says that whenever u r submitting a form it hits the URL given in action which in your case is 'Search/'. And u don't have any URL and views written for that. Also whenever u write search view try to call the methods in EmailCrawler class then it will work.

Comment: hey! Thank you for the response! But here is a couple things I don't understand. What do you mean by calling the methods in EmailCrawler?